# PowerShell cannot remove web server (IIS) support role?

Tags: powershell, iis, webserver

I am facing a problem where I cannot remove the "Web Server (IIS) Support" Role service that is part of the Application Server under Windows 2008 R2.

I am running PowerShell with admin privileges, and when I try to remove the Web Server (IIS) Support Role service using PS, I get the attached screenshot.

It says I should use the wizard to remove the entire IIS Role, but this is ridiculous. The wizard actually lets you uninstall JUST the Web Server (IIS) Support Role service without uninstalling IIS entirely, so I can only assume that what the PS error message is saying is wrong!!

Any ideas?

Comment: I could NOT add the screenshot because I dont have 10 points! Great

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. The problem is probably that additional depending features are installed.

Try this:

> Get-WindowsFeature AS-Web-Support | Remove-WindowsFeature

Maybe you would first run it with a -WhatIf switch to see what happens:

> Get-WindowsFeature AS-Web-Support | Remove-WindowsFeature -WhatIf